# Joins between three tables that do not take the condition inside the 'where' in Active Record quer

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an inquiry and I would like to know if you can help me.
In my application, I have the table’s employees, calendars and shifts. Here are the relations:

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :calendars
   has_many :shifts, :through => :calendars

class Shift < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :calendars
  has_many :employees, :through => :calendars

class Calendar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :shift
```

Therefore, I need to make a table where the following result is shown:

```
Name                |   Calendars.date  |   Calendars.date  | …
Employee.name       |   Shift.cod       |   Shift.cod       | …
Employee.name       |   Shift.cod       |   Shift.cod       | …
…
```

For this effect, I built query:

```
-@employees = Employee.joins(:calendars, :shifts).where("EXTRACT(MONTH FROM calendars.date) = ?", 12).uniq
```

The result get all the necessary data but I need that shows the data of a month, but is not taken what I put in the parameter in the where.

How could I build the query to filter by month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try `Employee.includes(:calendars, :shifts).where('calandar.month= ?', '<whatever month here>').references(:calendars)`

I'm not sure if the syntax is correct but basically you use `1st_obj.includes(obj).where(case).references(obj)` to do where on an object that belongs to another object

here's the [docs](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) for active_records `.includes` method